# jmeter security exception in api load testing

Tags: jmeter

I am doing the load testing of one of the web service which uses username pasalsword and password type authentication. While executing the script I am getting security exception in response. I have already made use of header manager, http authorization manager, bean shell preprocessor but all the approaches proved futile for me. Kindly guide me through this as I am stucked in between.
Thanks

Comment: You have to provide a lot more information. Where is what failing?

Comment: In my soap api there are following pre-requisite for authentication :        username = abc, pass = 123 & password type = text.         So my question is how to provide these value into jmeter so I can load test the api's?

Comment: Its a soap request and Username password and password type is used in request properties block of the soap request.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (don't use SOAP/XML-RPC Request or WebService(SOAP) Request)
2. Add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and configure username and password there.
3. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your Test Plan and inspect "Request" tab to ensure that "Authorization" header is being sent

   [image: Authorization Header]

   If you don't see the header you might need to change "Implementation" of the HTTP Request Sampler to "HttpClient3.1". The fastest and the easiest way of doing it for all the samplers in one shot is using [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults).

Check out [Take the Pain out of Load Testing Secure Web Services](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/take-pain-out-load-testing-secure-web-services) article to learn how to bypass different web services security types in JMeter test.